# Self-contained explanation for the CCG Principles

Tags: computational-linguistics, grammar

CCG is governed by a set of meta-rules which are commonly called "Principles". E.g.

- the Combinatory Projection Principle (CPP)
- the Projective Dependency Principle (PDP)

I have found most descriptions of these principles somewhat lacking in accessibility, something I can also say about discussions of why they are a good choice or trade-off in the limitations they impose.

Can you propose a very self-contained explanation of these principles, drawing as little as possible from earlier terminology?

Comment: Apologies to anyone coming here by the tags. There's no CCG tag on this community to constrain the audience.

Comment: The PDP means that the trees induced by categorial heads are projective (nontangled) which is a graph-theoretic notion meaning that no dependent can slip in between two higher nodes connected by an arc.